# Can access a host on port 9988 locally but not remotely

Tags: wcf, web-services, .net-4.0, web-config

I've set up a page and host it using bindings on ports 80 and 9988 for all incoming IPs. When testing locally on *localhost:port* it works for both the values but when accessing it remotely, only port 80 gives the desired result. The other one brings out connection time out.

First I thought it had to do with not recognized HTTP request so I added *http://* before the IP number but that didn't make any difference.

I'm guessing that I need to alter *web.config* but I'm unclear why (and how). The only change from the vanilla state I've made was to allow for multiple site bindings (`multipleSiteBindingsEnabled`), believing that's enough. It's not, apparently. :)

Eventually, I'll be hosting the site on several different ports (none of which is the default 80, though).

What need I to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Firewall...**

And since SO requires a minimum number of characters: check the settings of your firewall.

My experience is that when a connection isn't working but it should, you need to go "have-you-tried-turning-it-on-and-off-again" but web style: "have-you-checked-your-firewall-settings".

Comment: I'm so stupid some days... Nice reference to *IT support*. Loving that show.